# Retrieve Taxonomy Term ID from Term Name?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am using the following code to do a query on my database from within my page template by using the `term_taxonomy_id` which I retrieve from the end of the URL.

My URL looks something like this when using this template `http://mysite.com/county/18` with 18 in this case being the `term_taxonomy_id`

My code is as follows:

```
 <?php
 /*
 Template Name: County
 */
 $ex = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 //print_r($ex);

get_header(); 

// Global query variable
 global $woo_options; 
 global $wp_query;
 global $wpdb;
 $all_terms = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *  FROM wp_term_taxonomy,wp_terms WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.parent='{$ex[2]}' AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id=wp_terms.term_id ORDER BY wp_terms.name");

 //echo "SELECT name   FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id='{$ex[2]}'";
 $taxName = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name   FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id='{$ex[2]}'");
 foreach ( $taxName as $tx ) {

 $nameTaxnaomy = $tx->name;
 }

 $getPostID = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT object_id   FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id='{$ex[2]}'");
 foreach ( $getPostID as $tx1 ) {

  $post = $tx1->object_id;
 }

 ?>
```

**Question:**
I however need to change my URL structure to use the term_name at the end of the URL and not the taxonomy_id as above.

So now my URL looks like this `http://mysite.com/county/London`

When I do this, the database query does not work as it is exploding the URL to get the taxonomy_id at the end (18 in my example above) and then query the DB using that string.

**Actual Question:** Is there a way to get the `term_taxonomy_id` from the term name so I can use it in my db query?

I am thinking something like

```
//explode the url to get the term name
$dx = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

//now get the id from the term name
$ex = //get the term_taxonomy_id from $dx
```

Any help appreciated

Cheers

**Update** - With some tips below I have made the string look like this. My taxonomy name is called `location`

```
//define $ex byt ge_term_by
$ex = get_term_by('slug',explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'location');
```

When I echo `$ex` I don't get anything so something wrong still :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to use the get_term_by function from Wordpress. You can see the full documentation of it here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by .

The first 3 values are required, so you would need something like
get_term_by('slug',explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'your_term_category_here');

Hope that helps get you started!

Comment: Hi Thanks, yeah that could well help, but I am not too sure how to get those 3 x required values in my case as all I can get is the term name from the end of the URL. The slug is going to be based on the term name which should be the same as term name (just in lower case) and not sure about the category. I am just using a taxonomy with locations filled out...Do u know what the category might be?

Comment: That same function allows you to search by name instead of slug, see the Parameters section for '$field' in that link for a full list. To get the category, not 100% sure but once you have the term ID, try using this function and var_dump on what it returns http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_objects_in_term . You can also see the 'related' functions at the bottom of that page to see if one might be applicable